# Mule Munit mock http.uri.params

Tags: mocking, mule, url-parameters, munit

i have a flow where using http I have a GET call where it hits a like like

```
https://localhost:8081/ref/{ID}
```

I know i can get this parameter in code by using mel like:

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.ID]
```

I need to mock the uri params when i set the message but have not been sucessful. i have tried setting in the "set message" using this name

```
'http.uri.params'.ID
```

but it seems to error out when i run the test.

this is on mule server 3.7.3 using munit flows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the `http.uri.params` inbound property actually contains a `Map`, which in turn contains entries that represent the actual parameters.

You will need to set a mock inbound property named `http.uri.params` whose value is a Map that contains an entry with key "ID" and the value you want. Remember that in MEL, you can [create a map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-expression-language-reference#mapslistsarrays) using `[key1 : value1, key2 : value2, . . .]`.

Like so:

```
<mock:inbound-properties>
     <mock:inbound-property key="http.uri.params" value="#[['ID': '123']]"/>
</mock:inbound-properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ksmo92  you can try the following code. It worked well for me.

```
<munit:set payload="#['']" doc:name="Set http.uri.params">
        <munit:inbound-properties>
            <munit:inbound-property key="http.uri.params" value="#[['name': 'Anu']]"/>
        </munit:inbound-properties>
 </munit:set>
```